# How do I output the result generated in if-loop as one array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have my data as an array, and I want to extract every 7th value in the data. My code is like this:

```
import numpy as np

n=np.arange(0,100,1)
data=np.array(np.arange(0,100,1))

for n in n:
    if n%7==0:
        array=data[n]
```

But instead of one array, the 'array' in this output is actually a collection of single int objects(I would like to do this for float objects as well) that were looped over. How can I output one array or is if-loop not the way to do it?

Comment: have you tried [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)?

Comment: @joshmeranda Sorry, I should edit my post: I get a collection of single integer/float objects, not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
import numpy as np

n=np.arange(0,100,1)
data=np.array(np.arange(0,100,1))
data[::7]
```

for more informations: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The slice notation also seems very useful. I'll have a good read for sure.

Comment: @Limona2000 if the answer is exactly what you need, consider accepting it ;)

Comment: @mozway Good call, just didd! Sorry, just started using this :)